# why is my ec2-linux instance's ipv4 address different from SERVER_ADDR in php?

Tags: php, linux, apache, amazon-ec2, ip

My amw ec2-linux instance's IPv4 address is different from the Apache SERVER_ADDR variable(phpinfo()).  Why is that?  I searched on google "why is IPv4 address different from Apache SERVER_ADDR address" and nothing related came up.

Comment: Do you have a load balancer on it?

Comment: we're on basic ami ec2-linux instance(free tier t2 i believe) so i don't think we have any load balancers...

Comment: I bet that server_addr is showing the internal IP. You can view your internal IP while looking at the instance page in the AWS consol

Comment: Can you provide the two IP addresses (feel free to fake the last number to retain privacy)? I'd be interested to see whether they are in the range of public or private IP addresses.

Comment: I'm with John, I'd bet it has a public IP, the browser is getting the public IP while Datve2345 is looking at the private IP address of his instance.

Comment: Reading this will be helpful http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-ip-addressing.html